# Is there any way to get the time taken for index updation in Solr4.0?? Any plug in or something

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to `Solr`. I have created a collection and posted data in to it.
Now I am getting the index size and query processing time.
But is there any other way to know the index update duration ??